How is it possible to create >65000 entries in an ext4 directory despite the large_dir flag not being present?
So, I'm trying to understand FileSystem feature flags a little bit better.
For what I could find, according to man ext4 a single directory in a ext4 FS can host up to 64,998 subdirectories.

Normally, ext4 allows an inode to have no more than 65,000 hard links.  This applies to regular files as well as directories, which means that there can be no more than 64,998 subdirectories in a directory (because each of the '.' and '..' entries, as well as the directory entry for the directory in its parent directory counts as a hard link).

By using the FS feature large_dir, this limit should be lifted:

This feature increases the limit on the number of files per directory by raising the maximum size of directories and, for hashed b-tree directories (see dir_index), the maximum height of the hashed b-tree used to store the directory entries.

By using tune2fs, I checked the features enabled on my local ext4 FS:
$ sudo tune2fs -l /dev/disk/azure/scsi1/lun10-part1 | grep "Filesystem features"
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype needs_recovery extent 64bit flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file dir_nlink extra_isize metadata_csum

The dir_nlink feature is enabled, but from what I understood from the documentation, it should not enable having more than 65,000 subdirectories in a directory:

This feature lifts this limit by causing ext4 to use a link count of 1 to indicate that the number of hard links to a directory is not known when the link count might exceed the maximum count limit.

The dir_index flag is also enabled, but I fail to see how the underlying data structure is relevant for the subdirectory limits:

Use hashed b-trees to speed up name lookups in large directories.  This feature is supported by ext3 and ext4 file systems, and is ignored by ext2 file systems.

And yet I can create more than 65000 subdirectories. I have yet to find the actual limit, as the script I left running is still going strong:
for i in {1..500000}
do
  mkdir dir_$i
done

Are there overlaps between ext4 feature flags? Is enabling dir_nlink or dir_index equivalent to enable large_dir? And in case it is not - do these flags enable a subdir limit in between not using and using the large_dir flag?
These are the versions I'm using:
$ uname -a
Linux test-subdirectories 6.5.0-1024-azure #25~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 17 18:38:57 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.2 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy

Is there something I'm missing -or should be checking- to understand subdirectory limits in ext4?

As far as I can see, the manual excerpt you quoted –

Normally, ext4 allows an inode to have no more than 65,000 hard links. This applies to regular files as well as directories, which means that there can be no more than 64,998 subdirectories in a directory (because each of the '.' and '..' entries, as well as the directory entry for the directory in its parent directory counts as a hard link).

– has nothing whatsoever to do with large_dir and everything to do with dir_nlink. The quoted paragraph specifically talks about the number of hard links to a single entry (from the subdirectories' .. entries to the parent directory), and not about the number of entries in themselves.
The large_dir feature seems to allow directories with more than 2 GB worth of entries or more than 2 htree levels deep (see another thread about entry size; it seems to be hard to calculate exactly for dir_index filesystems, about 10M entries for "normal" filename lengths in the 24-32 character range), but it's certainly unrelated to the 65k limit).

Thank you! This info was really useful. The part of the doc that mislead my train of thought was this sentence: "which means that there can be no more than 64,998 subdirectories in a directory". So,if I understood this correctly: without dir_nlink, the limit would not be in the number of children "pointed to" by a parent, but in the parent being "pointed by"  > 64,988 children or more?

Hmm, I find this part of the text actually a bit confusing:

which means that there can be no more than 64,998 subdirectories in a directory (because each of the '.' and '..' entries, as well as the directory entry for the directory in its parent directory counts as a hard link).

While the . entry of directory D and the entry for D in its parent count as hard links, the relevant part glossed over there is that the .. entries of the _subdirectories` of D point back at D itself, also counting as hard links to D. Hence, the maximum link count limits the number of subdirectories a directory can have.
dir_nlink bypasses that by just not keeping count. The count is unnecessary anyway in the sense that all links to the directory can be found by reading the directory contents at looking at the pointed-to directories.
